# Is there a benefit from noexcept move-operations when using containers in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, move-semantics, c++17, noexcept

When reading about C++11 I had the feeling that when using the standard containers (like `std::vector`) with user defined datatypes one was encouraged to provide `noexcept` move operations, if at all, because then-and-only-then the containers would internally really move data around instead of copying.

When trying that out today I saw no difference with `-std=c++1y` (for C++14) and g++-4.8 even. Maybe I missed an update in the spec, maybe my example is wrong.

I compared three data structures that should be moveable with the differences

- moveable by default by following the "Rule Of Zero"
- moveable by providing move-ops *without* `noexcept`
- moveable by providing move-ops *with* `noexcept`

Framework:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream> // cout

using std::vector; using std::cout;    
using namespace std::chrono;

long long millisSeit(steady_clock::time_point start) {
    return duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now()-start).count();
}

namespace {    
constexpr size_t ITERATIONS = 1000*1000;

template<typename ELEM>
void timeStuff(std::string name) {
    cout << name << "...";
    auto start = steady_clock::now();
    std::vector<ELEM> data{};
    for(size_t idx=0; idx<ITERATIONS; ++idx) {
        data.emplace_back( idx % 1719 );
    }
    cout << " " << millisSeit(start) << " ms" << std::endl;
}
}
```

With my three datatypes:

```
struct RuleOfZeroVector {
    std::vector<int> val_;
    RuleOfZeroVector(int val) : val_(val, val) {}
};
struct MoveExceptVector {
    std::vector<int> val_;
    MoveExceptVector(int val) : val_(val, val) {}
    MoveExceptVector(MoveExceptVector&& o) /*noexcept*/ : val_{} { swap(val_, o.val_); }
    MoveExceptVector& operator=(MoveExceptVector&& o) /*noexcept*/ { swap(val_, o.val_); return *this; }
};
struct MoveNoExceptVector {
    std::vector<int> val_;
    MoveNoExceptVector(int val) : val_(val, val) {}
    MoveNoExceptVector(MoveNoExceptVector&& o) noexcept : val_{} { swap(val_, o.val_); }
    MoveNoExceptVector& operator=(MoveNoExceptVector&& o) noexcept { swap(val_, o.val_); return *this; }
};
```

And executing the timings:

```
int main() {
    timeStuff<RuleOfZeroVector>("RuleOfZeroVector");
    timeStuff<MoveExceptVector>("MoveExceptVector");
    timeStuff<MoveNoExceptVector>("MoveNoExceptVector");
}
```

With the results:

```
RuleOfZeroVector... 2461 ms
MoveExceptVector... 2472 ms
MoveNoExceptVector... 2468 ms
```

As you can see, no real difference.

I expected `MoveExceptVector` to be much slower then the other two, because I assumed `vector` will use a lot of copying when the internal data-structure grows. Wrong?

Comment: Add a copy ctor/assignment operator to `MoveExceptVector` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: There is no need for `vector::clear()` to move data around.  It simply runs the destructor of each element.  `vector::push_back` is the chief beneficiary of `noexcept` move construction.

Comment: "g++-4.8 even."  The 4.8 series was released in 2013. That is eons ago.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Ok, I thought `emplace_back` would also benefit a lot. Not as much as `push_back` of course.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't see why. Those should be generated by the compiler. Am I wrong?

Comment: @HowardHinnant yesyes, `clear()´ is not needed. remnant of other tests. I'll remove it.

Comment: @towi : Copy special members are _not_ implicitly generated if there is a corresponding user-defined move special member. If you had just done `MoveExceptVector(MoveExceptVector const&) = default;` and _tested_ it  you would have found the difference obvious. >_>

Comment: @ildjarn Technically, they are defined as deleted.

Comment: @T.C. : Indeed, but if I felt the need to give a detailed pedantic explanation, I would answer instead of comment. ;-]

Comment: You're overlooking that even if a function is not declared `noexcept` specifically, the compiler may deduce that it does not throw, and treat it as `noexcept`

Comment: @M.M no, that's not relevant here. The standard library can't detect that, it just uses the `noexcept` operator which only gives an answer based on whether something is `noexcept`.

Comment: @M.M There would also be potential ODR violations, because `vector` would take different code paths in different translation units, depending on whether enough code was visible for the compiler to deduce that something won't throw. The compiler is not allowed to change whether something is `noexcept(true)` or `noexcept(false)` according to how smart it is. It's a static property, which is fixed at compile-time, and the answer must be consistent.

Answer (score 4):

The relevant rule that `vector` uses for inserting a single element at the end is:

- If moving the type can't throw (i.e. move operations are marked `noexcept`) then move. In this case insertion at the end of a vector provides the strong exception-safety guarantee.
- If moving the type could throw, and it's copyable, then copy it instead. This ensures that if an exception is thrown we haven't moved some of the original objects, which would leave the original object in an unknown state. In this case you also get the strong exception-safety guarantee.
- Otherwise, since it's not copyable, you have no choice, you must move. If an exception is thrown some of the source objects might have been moved-from, and some won't be. In this case you only get the basic exception-safety guarantee.

In your example the objects are not copyable, because the user-provided move constructors and move assignment operators cause the implicit copy constructor to be defined as deleted. So `vector` has no choice. It must use the move operations even though they're not `noexcept`.

If you make the types copyable you should see a difference, with  `MoveExceptVector` being much slower, because now `vector` has a choice between doing moves that could throw or copying, so it chooses copying.

```
struct MoveExceptVector {
    std::vector<int> val_;
    MoveExceptVector(int val) : val_(val, val) {}
    MoveExceptVector(MoveExceptVector&& o) /*noexcept*/ : val_{} { swap(val_, o.val_); }
    MoveExceptVector& operator=(MoveExceptVector&& o) /*noexcept*/ { swap(val_, o.val_); return *this; }
    // ADDED:
    MoveExceptVector(const MoveExceptVector&) = default;
};
```

You can't expect it to choose copying if the object isn't copyable.